# How to close a popover with a button inside this popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have button. When somebody click on the button, a popover come. Inside the popover I have another button, and when somebody click on this button the popover will hide.

That's work fine, but for open another time the popover I have to click two times on the button.

My HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="actif" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<button type='button' class='annuler'>NOT</button>" data-html='true'>
                                ACTIVE
                            </button>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $(document).on("click", ".annuler", function () {
         $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    });
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in a different way:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".annuler", function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').trigger('click');
});
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" class="actif" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"
        data-content="<button type='button' class='annuler'>NOT</button>" data-html='true'>
    ACTIVE
</button>
```

Comment: Your answer work fine, but why?